# Check the input quantity is greater than the available quantity in database

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

What I want to do is checking whether the text box input quantity is greater than the available quantity in database. Alert should be displayed `onclick()` of the `ADD` button.

**`ADD` button**

```
<button type="button" name="btnSave" id="btnSave" onclick="submitdata(); resetform(); checkQty();">ADD</button>
```

**`checkQty()` function**

```
function checkQty() { 
    //Grab current forms input field values.
    var txtQuantity = document.getElementById("txtQuantity").value;
    var listItemName = document.getElementById("listItemName").value;

    //Connect to database and verify Quantity Ordered isnt greater than Quantity In Stock.
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/pms/includes/functions/qty_check.php",
        data: 'listItemName=' + listItemName + '&txtQuantity=' + txtQuantity,
        }).responseText;            
}
```

**qty_check.php**

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL );
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

//Start the Session
if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
{ 
   session_start(); 
} 

include_once("../../config.php");
require __DIR__."../../dbutil.php";

if(!empty($_POST['txtQuantity'])){$qty =  $_POST['txtQuantity'];}
if(!empty($_POST['listItemName'])){$item =  $_POST['listItemName'];}

$results = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM purchase_items WHERE item_id= ".$_GET['listItemName']"");

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
{
    $tb_qty=$row["avail_qty"];
}

if($tb_qty < $qty){ ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Quantity exceeds the stock limit");
</script>

<?php
}
?>
```

I tried a lot, but I couldn't fix this. Appreciate any help.

Comment: what exactly is the error?is your javascript function working?

Comment: @GraveyardQueen it doesn't display any error, but alert is not displaying as expected.

Comment: are you getting results from your query?

Comment: @GraveyardQueen yes, when I give the exact item id to the `WHERE` clause.

`SELECT * FROM purchase_items WHERE item_id= 43`

Answer (score 1):

You should not print out html directly from an ajax call. You should echo out some json that you can parse on the front end to get the information. using

```
echo json_encode(['key' => 'value'])
```

here is your code, with a little modification. I added a `dataType` to the ajax query and a `done` function that is called when the ajax request has finished.

```
function checkQty() { 
  //Grab current forms input field values.
  var txtQuantity = document.getElementById("txtQuantity").value;
  var listItemName = document.getElementById("listItemName").value;

  //Connect to database and verify Quantity Ordered isnt greater than Quantity In Stock.
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/pms/includes/functions/qty_check.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      listItemName: listItemName,
      txtQuantity: txtQuantity
    }
  }).done(function(response){
    alert('check your console!')
    console.log('this is the response', response.available);
  })
}
```

**qty_check.php**

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL );
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

//Start the Session
if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
{ 
   session_start(); 
} 

include_once("../../config.php");
require __DIR__."../../dbutil.php";

if(!empty($_POST['txtQuantity'])){$qty =  $_POST['txtQuantity'];}
if(!empty($_POST['listItemName'])){$item =  $_POST['listItemName'];}

$results = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM purchase_items WHERE item_id= ".$_GET['listItemName']"");

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
{
    $tb_qty=$row["avail_qty"];
}
// echo out some json to send to the front end
echo json_encode(['available' => $tb_qty < $qty]);
?>
```

Comment: Sorry friend, still nothing displays, and no errors. Do I need to include json library kind of thing, if so, how to do it? I have no experience in json.

Comment: If there is no errors check your console for the console.log value. You don't need any libraries to use json in either php or javascript.

Comment: I check the browser console for errors. No errors on it. Otherwise, is their any way to check as you stated?

Comment: I have not run the php and am not going to. You should check to see if the php is failing by debugging the code before the last echo with a `die('message');` to make sure all parts of the code are working. and check the *network* tab of chrome to see if the ajax is successful.